# setMouseCallback onmouse is not defined

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, signals

```
def __init__(self):
    super(FindWindow, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('D:/Python/Projects/Sensor/roi.ui', self)
    self.init_ui()

def init_ui(self):
    self.pushButton_roi.clicked.connect(self.open_picture)

def onMouse(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global drawing, ix, iy
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix, iy = x, y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing:
            cv2.rectangle(param, (ix, iy), (x, y), (0, 0, 0), -1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        cv2.rectangle(param, (ix, iy), (x, y), (0, 0, 0), -1)

def open_picture(self, what):
    img = cv2.imread(file_directory)
    temp = what
    print(temp)
    cv2.namedWindow('paint')
    cv2.setMouseCallback('paint', onMouse, param=img)

    while True:
        cv2.imshow('paint', img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        if k == 27:
            break
```

I'm trying to use mousecallback function on pyqt to set the ROI from a picture. 
I went over an example code of mousecallback function, and the example code worked without a problem.
Then, I implemented it with pyqt as shown above, and now it gives me an error as below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/Projects/Sensor/one_detect_main.py", line 49, in open_picture
    cv2.setMouseCallback('paint', onMouse, param=img)
NameError: name 'onMouse' is not defined
```

I don't know what the difference is between the example code and my code.
Here's the example code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from random import shuffle
import math

mode, drawing = True, False
ix, iy = -1, -1
B = [i for i in range(256)]
G = [i for i in range(256)]
R = [i for i in range(256)]


def onMouse(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global ix, iy, drawing, mode, B, G, R

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix, iy = x, y
        shuffle(B), shuffle(G), shuffle(R)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing:
            if mode:
                cv2.rectangle(param, (ix, iy), (x, y), (B[0], G[0], R[0]), -1)
            else:
                r = (ix-x) ** 2 + (iy-y)**2
                r = int(math.sqrt(r))
                cv2.circle(param, (ix, iy), r, (B[0], G[0], R[0]), -1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        if mode:
            cv2.rectangle(param, (ix, iy), (x, y), (B[0], G[0], R[0]), -1)
        else:
            r = (ix-x)**2 + (iy-y)**2
            r = int(math.sqrt(r))
            cv2.circle(param, (ix, iy), r, (B[0], G[0], R[0]), -1)

def mouseBrush():
    global mode

    img = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), np.uint8)
    cv2.namedWindow('paint')
    cv2.setMouseCallback('paint', onMouse, param=img)

    while True:
        cv2.imshow('paint', img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        if k == 27:
            break
        elif k == ord('m'):
            mode = not mode

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

mouseBrush()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: does the example work for you?

Comment: Even though that first bit of code is ripped out of context (and thus **not** a [mcve]), the fact there's an `__init__` and that all the functions other than `onMouse` have `self` as the first parameter suggests that all of that is part of a class definition.... which would explain why trying to refer to `onMouse` as if it was freestanding is not working.

Comment: @DanMašek You're right. I problem has been solved by adding self to onMouse.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand for adding self to onMouse. I meet the same error, I don't know how to solve this problem. Would you mind to give me more detail?

Answer (score -1):

From the example code, onMouse is a function that they defined which takes in an event and other parameters. By using mouseCallBack function, onMouse will get called whenever the mouse does something.

```
def onMouse(event, x, y, flags, param):
 # handle the event here
```

Also, notice that inside onMouse they are handling different events

```
if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
 # do something  
elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
 # do something
```